# Cancel/Force Stop an Input and Output stream executed through SwingWorker

Tags: java, swingworker

I wanted to stop the Input and Output stream executed through `SwingWorker` `doInBackground`. Whenever I cancel the task, it's still create the file (see the code below). The task is simple, "for every file name (a `String`) specified, output this file with the given name" (something like that).

I wrote the IO stream in a separate package/class. So the code is like:

```
public class ResourceFileExtract(String outputFile) {
  InputStream inputStream = null;
  OutputStream outputStream = null;
  try {
    inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/someFile");
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    int numbers;
    while ((numbers = inputStream.read(bytes)) > 1) {
      outputStream.write(bytes, 0, length)
    }
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();
  } /* Other codes here */
}
```

The SwingWorker setup.

```
private class BackgroundTask extends SwingWorker<Integer, String> {
  @Override
  protected Integer doInBackground() {
    /* Some codes here */
    if (!isCancelled()) {
       for (/* Loop statement */) {
         try {
           // Input and Output stream called from a class...
           ResourceFileExtract fileExtract = new ResourceFileExtract(specifiedOutputName);
           System.out.println("Done (file extracted successfully)");
         } catch (IOException ex) {
           System.out.println("Error (unable to read resource file)");
           return 0;
         }
       }
    } else {
      // These texts are not printed in console...
      System.out.println("Cancelled (I/O streaming stopped)");
      return 0;
    }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

SwingWorker executed with:

```
JButton start = new JButton("Start");
start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    BackgroundTask bgTask = new BackgroundTask();
    bgTask.execute();
  }
});
```

And cancelled with:

```
JButton stop = new JButton("Stop");
stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    bgTask.cancel(true);
  }
});
```

While debugging the program, the cancellation message is not printed in the console, meaning the task is not cancelled whenever I hit the cancel button and the output file still created with the success message. How can I stop this one? Any help?

Comment: Well, your worker will need to maintain an instance reference to the `ResourceFileExtract`, the `ResourceFileExtract` will then need to provide some means of been cancelled and dispose of its resource correctly

Comment: @MadProgrammer So should I make the `ResourceFileExtract` a local class along with my worker?

Comment: I don't think "local class" has anything to do with this. 1) The worker needs a field that refers to the resource object, and 2) this object needs to somehow be able to cancel itself when you want it to do so. This needs to be part of its nature, it's code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, your `ResourceFileExtract` class needs someway to be cancelled, for example...

```
public class ResourceFileExtract {

    private String outputFile;
    private AtomicBoolean cancelled = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public ResourceFileExtract(String outputFile) {
        this.outputFile = outputFile;
    }

    public void cancel() {
        cancelled.set(true);
    }

    public void extract() throws IOException {

        try (InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/someFile");
                 OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int numbers;
            while (!cancelled.get() && (numbers = inputStream.read(bytes)) > 1) {
                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, numbers);
            }
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            throw exp;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `SwingWorker`, you'll need to provide some kind "stop" method of your own (as `cancel` is `final` :P) and I can't guarantee that any property change event would be triggered because of the call to `cancel` itself.

The worker would need to maintain a reference to the extractor created by the `doInBackground` method to allow it to successfully trigger the cancel in the extractor

Comment: Okay I'll try this and give the result right away :)

Comment: I'd only be worried about the ability to interrupt the blocking i/o

Comment: The result is just what I wanted and expected. But the cancel message still doesn't prints out which is the only remaining problem. Anyways I'm going to work on it. Tyvm again sir.

Comment: The "cancelled" message would (in your case) only print out if the worker was cancelled before it run. Try printing it after the `ResourceFileExtract` returns (checking to see if `isCancelled` is true)

Comment: Since the cancellation can only be triggered by another thread, the variable `cancelled` should be declared `volatile` as otherwise there is no guaranty the the loop within `extract()` will ever notice a change.

Comment: @Holger Yes, you are correct, but there's actually a better solution (IMHO)

Comment: If all you are doing is `get` and `set`, an `AtomicBoolean` does not provide any advantage over a `volatile boolean`. In fact, it *is* an encapsulated `volatile boolean` field and `get` and `set` are simple reads and writes of the field. `AtomicBoolean` becomes interesting when you need the atomic `getAndSet` or `compareAndSet`. When you don’t need these, it’s just overkill.

Comment: @Holger In my experience, it's more reliable the `volatile`, if you prefer `volatile`, then you're free to use it

Comment: There’s nothing in it that would make it more reliable, however, if you prefer it, it doesn’t hurt. But for reliability, you should make `cancelled` a `final` variable then.